# CMake: Can we specify include directories for a specific set of files not forming an executable or lib?

Tags: c++, cmake

If I have this source tree:

```
C:\app:
    src:
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp --> #include "acme/header_only_lib/api.h"

D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib:
    api.h --> #include "detail.h"
    detail.h
```

Without using symlink tricks, and without adding files to the 3rdparty folders, if I must retain `#include "acme/header_only_lib/api.h"` in `main.cpp`, how should I specify the include directories in CMake such that `api.h` can see `detail.h`, **without** adding global include directory of `D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib`? The header-only-lib is not an executable nor library target, and its code is not modifiable by me. I also don't want to pollute my global include directories by adding `D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib` because the filenames inside there are too common and will easily clash with other libraries/future code.

Is there a CMake mechanism where I can say:
**Only** for `D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib\api.h`, add `D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib` as the include directory?

Comment: Add both `D:\3rdparty` and `D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib` as include paths.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't specific enough: I was trying not to pollute the global includes by bringing in D:\3rdparty\acme\header_only_lib globally, as there is a real problem of file  name clashes. Do you know of some way of specifying "local" includes (visible only to say, files inside header_only_lib) instead of "global" includes?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) or `target_include_directories`:

```
include_directories("D:\3rdparty")
```

OR with `target_include_directories` if you want to make this change only for the `main` target:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC "D:\3rdparty")
```

Then you can just `#include "acme/header_only_lib/api.h"` or `#include <acme/header_only_lib/api.h>`

### Header only lib

If you want to do this for `header-only-lib` only, you need to do this in it's CMake file. First add the library as `INTERFACE` with no source files:

```
add_library(header-only INTERFACE)
```

Then include directories for it:

```
target_include_directories(header-only INTERFACE include-dir-for-header-only)
```

Then link it to the main target

```
find_library(HeaderOnly
    NAMES header-only
    HINTS "D:\3rdparty\path-to-lib"
)
target_link_libraries(main header-only)
```

Comment: But ```api.h``` still can't see ```detail.h```, right?

Comment: if `api.h` and `detail.h` are in the same dir, and `api.h` is include `detail.h`, it should be able to see it.

Comment: ```api.h``` can see ```detail.h``` only if A) The file that uses them (i.e. the file that is ```#include```-ing them) is side-by-side with them, OR B) ```api/detail.h```'s containing folder is in the include directories. The search mechanism of ```#include``` uses 1) the "calling" file's folder, and 2) the include directories. For example, on **gcc**: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html, and on **msvc**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=vs-2019 Files being siblings do not guarantee mutual visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

To add a directory to the global list of include directories, you use e.g.

```
include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty )
```

Note that you should not hardcode absolute paths (like `D:\`) into your CMakeLists.txt as that makes it impossible to build your project in any other location. CMake offers variables like `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` for just that purpose.

If you want to add a directory to the list of include directories for a specific part of your build only, you use e.g.

```
target_include_directories( app PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty )
```

This adds the directory *only for the target (executable / library) `app`*.

Note that, if your `acme/header_only_lib` is supposed to be installed alongside with the `app` binaries, this approach won't work, as your acme headers would need to "see" each other on the client's machine, which is unlikely if they reside in the `acme/header_only_lib` subdirectory but address each other without subdirs. That would require your client (who isn't using *your* `CMakeLists.txt` for his builds) to add `acme/header_only_lib` to the include paths for your header lib to work -- you should not do that.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last paragraph, let me digest that a bit. But regarding ```target_include_directories```: The ```acme/header_only_lib``` is not a binary target (neither executable nor library) but purely header files. Is it then still possible to use ```target_include_directories```? As I understand, that's not possible. I am trying to avoid a situation where, in order for ```api.h``` to see ```detail.h```, I add their parent folder to global include, because this makes it much easier to have file name clashes.

Comment: @moog That is what the last paragraph is about. A header lib for "external" use -- be it by `app` or the client of your project -- should not need any extension of the include paths. You should `#include "acme/lib/detail.h"` there. Adding to the include path, if at all, should be used for "internal" headers only (those used by you for building your binary, which aren't installed anywhere outside your source tree).

Comment: *"You should #include ```"acme/lib/detail.h"``` **there**"*: By "there", do you mean ```api.h``` should be doing ```#include "acme/lib/detail.h"```, so as to spare its clients from extending their global includes? Completely agree! (If that's what you meant). It's just too bad many source-only libraries don't do this. And clients using those libraries end up having to pollute global includes just to accommodate their implementation-detail #include lookups. I was wondering if CMake has any mechanism to extend includes just to a specific set of source files that do not form an executable/lib.

Comment: @moog: That was indeed what I meant. -- "I was wondering...": How should CMake extend the compiler's include path for something that isn't compiled (like the contents of a header-only library)? Only `api` is actually processed by the compiler. If it includes your acme/header_only_lib headers, fine, but that is part of the `acme` target. Anyone (other than `api`) that will use your acme library will have his/her own compiler run, which might not even be under control of a (any) CMake build...